# Разделить данные

Tags: jquery, json, javascript

Доброе время суток). Есть JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
url: "data.json",
dataType: "text",
success: function(data) {

var json = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(json, function(key,value) {
document.write('<div id="post">' + value.name + '</div>');
}); 
 }
});
});
```

И JSON:

```
{"post1":{"name":"Hello!","rating":1,"img":"/p1.jpg"},"post2":{"name":"Launch new service","rating":1,"img":"/p2.jpg"}}
```

Как можно увидеть по JS, читается `name` у всех `post` и заносится в один `div`, в итоге получаем в `#post`:

```
Hello!Launch new service
```

Можно ли как-то вывести это по отдельности? Т.е. `post1` в своем `div`, а `post2` в  другом `div`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то [так](http://jsfiddle.net/t34vytLf/)

Comment: Спасибо, хоть я и сделал чуть-чуть по другому, отмечу как решение